# webtechnick Facebook plugin autologin issue

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using webtechnick Facebook plugin and have successfully integrated it with my PHP site. Login and logout are working fine, but I am facing an issue when I login into Facebook in one tab and my website in other tab.

In this case my website retrieves the Facebook data automatically without clicking the Facebook login button in my login page. The website should retrieve the Facebook data only if I click the Facebook login button in my login page. How can I resolve this?

Here is my code in FacebookHelper.php:

```
public function init($options = null, $reload = true) {
        $options = array_merge(array(
            'perms' => 'email'
        ), (array)$options);
        if ($appId = FacebookInfo::getConfig('appId')) {
            $init = '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
            $init .= $this->Html->scriptBlock("
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '$appId', // App ID
            channelURL : '../../Vendor/channel.php', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });


        // Checks whether the user is logged in
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                // alert('You are connected');
            } else {
                // no user session available, someone you dont know
                // alert('You are disconnected');
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // the user has just logged in
                // alert('You just logged in facebook from somewhere');
            } else {
                // the user has just logged out
                // alert('You just logged out from faceboook');
            }
        });



        // Other javascript code goes here!

    };

    // logs the user in the application and facebook
    function login(redirection){
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if(response.authResponse) {
                // user is logged in
                // console.log('Welcome!');
                if(redirection != null && redirection != ''){
                    top.location.href = redirection;
                }
            } else {
                // user could not log in
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {scope: '" . $options['perms'] . "'});
    }

    // logs the user out of the application and facebook
    function logout(redirection){
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            // user is logged out
            // redirection if any
            if(redirection != null && redirection != ''){
                top.location.href = redirection;
            }
        });
    }

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/".$this->locale."/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());");
            return $init;
        } else {
            return "<span class='error'>No Facebook configuration detected. Please add the facebook configuration file to your config folder.</span>";
        }
    }
```

Login page (login.ctp):

```
 <?php 
    echo $this->Facebook->html();

        echo $this->Facebook->login(array('id'=>'facebookbut','img' => 'facebooklogin.png','redirect' =>'/'));

    echo $this->Facebook->init();
    ?>
```

Comment: Much better than your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021273/webtechnick-facebook-plugin-browser-issue), +1! To avoid clutter it is generally better to just improve your previous question, rather than asking a new one, but np.